# Schema specified is not valid:Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database first MVC application  I create table in sql server and do Update model form database  in EF edmx it work fine but when I change data type of a filed of a table  and Update model from database it give the following error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> MRBQModel1.msl(143,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not
>   valid. The type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member
>   'QuestionLabelId' in type 'QuestionDbModel.T_QestionLabelText' is not
>   compatible with
>   'SqlServer.varchar[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=50,Unicode=False,FixedLength=False]'
>   of member 'QuestionLabelId' in type
>   'QuestionDbModel.Store.T_QestionLabelText'.

Please give a sollution

Comment: can you post your entity and schema of the table?

Comment: you need to edit your post to specify the details needed to solve this issue, instead of editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error message says that datatype of QuestionLabelId is `integer` in your entity, whereas the database has the same field with datatype `nvarchar`. So you must have same datatype at both places.

How are you doing with Entity framework? I mean is it a code first or data first?